# What is the electron dot structure of an alkyne?

Tags: hydrocarbons, structural-formula

I am trying to determine the electron dot structure of an alkyne like $\ce{C2H2}$.

I know that hydrocarbons with at least one carbon-carbon triple bond are called alkynes, and their general formula is $\ce{C_{n}H_{2n-2}}$, where $n$ is number of carbon atoms.

So what will the electron dot structure of $\ce{C2H2}$ look like?

Comment: Have you drawn electron dot structures for alkenes? Recall that pairs of dots represent covalent bonds. As you know that an alkyne has a carbon-carbon triple bond, this should indicate the correct number of dots between the carbons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon needs four electrons to fill its octet.  In a $\ce{C-H}$ covalent bond carbon shares one electron with hydrogen.  A triple consists of one σ covalent bond and two π covalent bonds.  The carbons share two electrons in each of these bonds; in total six electrons are shared between them.  You can draw this as a dot structure:

$$\ce{H:C:::C:H}$$